# How do I swap the rows and different values in my function?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, 2d

I am currently in a coding class and I am trying to learn Python (Python 3) and I have written some code here for an assignment but I am apparently getting the swapping wrong and I don't know how to fix it. I have the assignment's instructions and I also have a comment on my code that I need help understanding. Can someone please show me how to flip the rows by swapping the different values?

**Here are the instructions:**

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
def flipIt(array):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        length = len(array[i])
        for j in range(length // 2):
            temp = array[i][j]
            array[i][j] = array[i][length - 1 - j]
            array[i][length - 1 - j] = temp


pic = [['@', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@'],
       ['@', '@', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@'],
       ['@', ' ', '@', ' ', ' ', '@'],
       ['@', ' ', ' ', '@', ' ', '@'],
       ['@', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@', '@'],
       ['@', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@']]


flipIt(pic)
for i in pic:
    for j in i:
        print(j,end=' ')
    print()
```

**Here is the comment:**

[image]

**How do I do what the comment says?**

Comment: Add code as text in code format - people tend to downvote questions with images to show their code

Comment: Hi Audrey, please copy paste the code instead of taking a screenshot. Right now, if someone is trying to help you, they would have to copy your code by hand.

Answer (score 0):

The `flipIt` function is unneeded since Python has a built-in way to do this.  All you need to do is replace:

```
flipIt(pic)
```

with:

```
pic.reverse()
```

(You could also do something like `flipIt = lambda img: img.reverse()` if you wanted an extra layer of abstraction in there, or because the assignment required you to have a function that was specifically called `flipIt`.)

The `list.reverse()` method operates on any list and does an in-place reversal of its elements.  Since `pic` is a list of rows in the image, reversing the order has the effect of flipping it vertically.

You can also simplify your `print` loop by using `str.join()` to turn each row into a single string.

```
>>> pic = [['@', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@'],
...        ['@', '@', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@'],
...        ['@', ' ', '@', ' ', ' ', '@'],
...        ['@', ' ', ' ', '@', ' ', '@'],
...        ['@', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@', '@'],
...        ['@', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@']]
>>> pic.reverse()  # flip the rows from top to bottom
>>> for row in pic:
...     print(' '.join(row))
...
@         @
@       @ @
@     @   @
@   @     @
@ @       @
@         @
```

Comment: I edited my code in the above post and I tried this and still got the wrong answer. Is there another way that I could do this?

Comment: Pasting my results of running the code into this answer.  It produces exactly the output you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code actually works just fine. You just forgot to return your flipped array from your function:

```
def flipit(array):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        length = len(array[i])
        for j in range(length // 2):
            temp = array[i][j]
            array[i][j] = array[i][length - 1 - j]
            array[i][length -1 -j] = temp
    return array

pic = [['@', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@'],
    ['@', '@', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@'],
    ['@', ' ', '@', ' ', ' ', '@'],
    ['@', ' ', ' ', '@', ' ', '@'],
    ['@', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@', '@'],
    ['@', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@']
   ]

x = flipit(pic)

print(x)
```

Comment: I edited my code in the above post into code format and I tried this but I got it wrong. Is there another way I can fix my code?

Comment: What do you mean you "got it wrong"? Did it change something? What does it do now? etc... Please update your question with any new element that can help us help you

Comment: this is giving me the right answer:

[['@', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@'], ['@', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@', '@'], ['@', ' ', ' ', '@', ' ', '@'], ['@', ' ', '@', ' ', ' ', '@'], ['@', '@', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@'], ['@', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@']]

 is your code being graded for just the correct answer or is it looking for the "best" way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Mmh, it took me some time to realize the problem because flipping this picture vertically and horizontally gives the same result. In your case, what you want to do is:

```
def flipIt(array):
    height = len(array)
    for i in range(len(array) // 2):
        temp = array[i]
        array[i] = array[height-1-i]
        array[height-1-i] = temp
    # No need for return because it is modified in place

pic = [['@', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@'],
       ['@', '@', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@'],
       ['@', ' ', '@', ' ', ' ', '@'],
       ['@', ' ', ' ', '@', ' ', '@'],
       ['@', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@', '@'],
       ['@', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@']]


flipIt(pic)
for i in pic:
    for j in i:
        print(j,end=' ')
    print()
```

Of course, as Sam Stafford suggested, you can make it even simpler (given that you are allowed) with

```
def flipIt(array):
    array.reverse()
```